# With CSS, what good is 'width' when you have to end up specifying 'min-width' and 'max-width' anyway?

Tags: html, css

I know I don't understand some of the things CSS does from time to time, but, often times, I set the 'width' style to an element (say an input element), but if there is space it grows to fill it (as if it were set to auto) and (say for a select element) if there are no option elements, it will shrink to the smallest size (when 'width' is still set).

I realize that these scenarios are easily handled with the 'min-width' and 'max-width' CSS styles, but my question is: Why even have a 'width' style when it doesn't really set anything anyway (seemingly)? What's really going on in this scenario?

I am seeking an answer that will benefit my understanding of how CSS behaves in this scenario.

--------------------------------------**UPDATE**---------------------------------------------

As others here have shown me, the behavior I was observing, must have been caused by some other factor (maybe because the input elements were in td elements? Sometimes tables do appear to do weird things), as clearly the jsFiddles shown here don't duplicate my scenario. Not sure how I misinterpreted CSS like this, but anyway, this question has still been helpful in that I benefited from the answers/explanations given as to when/why "min-width" and "max-width" should be used vs. simply setting "width".

In short, "width", "max-width", and "min-width" certainly have their uses, given the right scenario.

Comment: `min-width` and `max-width` don't work in IE8 and below. You need to use `width` in that case I believe.

Comment: Cannot reproduce: I don't see [the input that I specified a width on](http://jsbin.com/iredut/1/edit) expanding to fill the available space. Since your question is predicated on that not working, it doesn't make a whole lot of sense.

Comment: @VoidKing Oh dear, `input` <> `select`: See your [updated fiddle](http://jsbin.com/ofofun/1/edit).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the reason is this:

- width - translate this to "this is the width I want for my element".
- min-width - translate this to "please do not make my element width smaller than this value".
- max-width - translate this to "please do not make my element width greater than this value".

Comment: Exactly, it doesn't get any simpler than this. It's not like there isn't a single scenario ever where you'd want a fixed width for an element.

Comment: @DwB Translating width to "this is the width I want for my element", why does it get ignored (at least for input elements, although I see it happening with other elements from time to time) when there is more space available (using percentages for width)?

Comment: @DwB I guess my problem is that, when I set a 'width' style, I want it to be that width, with no exception (provided the rule isn't overwritten), otherwise, why even have a width style. I get the browser compatibility thing, though. That does make sense there.

Comment: All you ever do with width, min-width, and max-width is suggest the desired width, desired min-width, and the desired  max-width.  It is the domain of the presenter (the browser) to respect or ignore your desired values.  complient browsers respect them.  IE 7 and earlier laugh at them.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont know the `original width` of a container,and want it to restrict it to some width,then `max-width` is used

If the you want to spread out contents in a container,but dont want to it to exceed 200px,then you  max-width is used,,,,,,,,

Consider this scenario

1.You are using `width`

2.(you dont know the width of the container)

3.You dont want it to exceed 200px

If you blindly put `width="200px"`,then chances are there that the container may be only of 150px and 50px gets wasted in the screen.Hence max-width is used

Answer (score 0):

So I did some digging for you. 97ldave is correct, it has to do with browser compatibility and screen resolution differences between users.

Take a look at [w3schools - Width Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_width.asp) and then [w3schools- Max-width Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_max-width.asp). Scroll to the section called "browser compatibility." It looks like `Width-min max` are back supported farther in IE than the others.

Hope that helps, that website rocks as a quick reference.

Comment: w3schools is a bad reference site.  here is the argument against w3schools:  w3fools.com

Comment: To each their own, just giving some quick fax and not plainly regurgitating the definition for the OP.